Thunderbird 115.13.0 cannot connect authenticated user via OAuth2 to Microsoft Outlook365
I've Thunderbird 115.13.0 on Ubuntu 22.04 and I have my email which is configured properly automatically by Thunderbird for IMAP and SMTP servers from Microsoft outlook office 365.
However, now it has problem for both IMAP and SMTP (I can authenticate with OAuth2 in a login page inside Thunderbird without issue).
The issue is:
The mail server for account xxx@yyy responded: User is authenticated but not connected 

My email belongs to an organisation and I don't have admin rights to change anything to authentication.
Any helps would be appreciated for that issue.
